# Dimple.js scatter plot not drawing correctly in Firefox v. 38.0.5

Tags: javascript, firefox, d3.js, dimple.js

I'm learning to use d3 and dimple, and using a sample chart as a guide (dimplejs.org/examples_viewer.html?id=scatter_standard), I tried to make my own simple scatter plot.

Here is the script I used to generate the chart:

```
var chart2 = function chart1(city) {
var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 767, 670);
  d3.tsv("test2.tsv", function (data) {
    data = dimple.filterData(data, "Region", city);
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 65, 650, 390);
    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Percent");
    y.tickFormat = "%";
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Period");             
    myChart.addSeries(["Period", "Total"], dimple.plot.bubble);
    myChart.defaultColors = [new dimple.color("red")];
    myChart.staggerDraw = true;
    myChart.ease = "linear";
    myChart.draw(500);

  });};
  var cityPrompt = prompt("Enter the name of the city:");
  chart2(cityPrompt);
```

It runs just fine in Chrome (Version 43.0.2357.130 m): [chart for city "Alpha" in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tY7Qh.jpg)

but when I run it in Firefox (Version 38.0.5) the chart is drawn based on the y axis, so that the plot is a decreasing trend from left to right, in the order of highest percent to lowest percent: [chart for city "Alpha" in Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4ajv.jpg)

I want and expect the chart to draw the way it draws in Chrome, and I can't figure out how to code it so that it also draws correctly in Firefox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the data in the tsv file I'm using:

```
Region  Period  "Total" "Percent"                           
Alpha   1   123 .24                     
Alpha   2   167 .33                     
Alpha   3   209 .67                     
Alpha   4   121 .56                         
Alpha   5   195 .45                         
Alpha   6   132 .81                         
Alpha   7   234 .94                         
Beta    1   99  .02                         
Beta    2   127 .03                         
Beta    3   709 .21                         
Beta    4   85  .37                         
Beta    5   92  .11                         
Beta    6   238 .27                         
Beta    7   154 .70                         
Gamma   1   383 .15                         
Gamma   2   226 .23                         
Gamma   3   167 .41                         
Gamma   4   62  .64                         
Gamma   5   87  .78                         
Gamma   6   172 .55                         
Gamma   7   369 .88
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the difference is that Chrome is parsing those numbers as dates and Firefox is rejecting them.  Strictly speaking I'd say Firefox is correct here, the logic is that unless the categorical axis has date values, sort the values descending by y value however Chrome is really lenient on what it considers to be a date.  You can however avoid any confusion by explicitly choosing what to order by:

```
x.addOrderRule("Period");
```

Here it is in place:

```
var chart2 = function chart1(city) {
var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 767, 670);


d3.tsv("test2.tsv", function (data) {
    data = dimple.filterData(data, "Region", city);
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, data);
    myChart.setBounds(60, 65, 650, 390);
    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Percent");
    y.tickFormat = "%";
    var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Period");      
    x.addOrderRule("Period");       
    myChart.addSeries(["Period", "Total"], dimple.plot.bubble);
    myChart.defaultColors = [new dimple.color("red")];
    myChart.staggerDraw = true;
    myChart.ease = "linear";
    myChart.draw(500);

});};
var cityPrompt = prompt("Enter the name of the city:");
chart2(cityPrompt);
```

Comment: Thank you, that did solve the issue.  Your explanation makes perfect sense.  In the future, I'll probably try to leave less ambiguity in my code about how I want the data ordered so that I don't leave room for browsers to interpret it differently.